# STM32F103RB Nucleo transmit and receive usart

Tags: c, microprocessors

I have some problems with transmiting and receiving using usart. First informations that I want transmit are writen to circle buffer. Then indormations  are send but some informations are lost.

Variables

```
enum {
    BUF_SIZE = 100
};
char BUF_T[BUF_SIZE], BUF_R[BUF_SIZE];
uint8_t R_EMPTY = 0, R_BUSY = 0, T_EMPTY = 0, T_BUSY = 0;
```

Transmiting

```
void Send(void) {
    uint8_t index = T_EMPTY;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        BUF_T[index] = i+'0';
        index++;
        if (index >= BUF_SIZE) {
            index = 0;
        }

    }
    __disable_irq();
    if (T_BUSY == T_EMPTY
            && __HAL_UART_GET_FLAG(&huart2,UART_FLAG_TXE) == SET) {
        T_EMPTY = index;
        T_BUSY++;
        uint8_t tmp = BUF_T[T_BUSY];

        if (T_BUSY >= BUF_SIZE) {
            T_BUSY = 0;
        }
        HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t*) &tmp, 1);
    } else {
        T_EMPTY = index;
    }
    __enable_irq();
}

void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) {

    //if (huart->Instance == USART2) {

    if (T_BUSY != T_EMPTY) {
        __disable_irq();
        T_BUSY++;
        uint8_t tmp = BUF_T[T_BUSY];
        if (T_BUSY >= BUF_SIZE) {
            T_BUSY = 0;
        }

        HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t*) &tmp, 1);
        __enable_irq();
    }else {
        Send();
    }

    //}

}
```

[Screen from hterm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfU9H.png)

On picture can be seen that from time to time one char is lost. I don't understant why?

Regarding receiving can somebody tell mi if it OK?

```
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart) {

    //if (huart->Instance == USART2) {
    uint8_t tmp = BUF_R[R_EMPTY];
    R_EMPTY++;
    if (R_EMPTY >= BUF_SIZE) {
        R_EMPTY = 0;
    }
    HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t*) &tmp, 1);
    //}
}
```

Comment: Im not sure if this is your only problem, but it appears you are indexing `BUF_R` and `BUF_T` once too many times; ie, the logic should be `if (R_EMPTY >= BUF_SIZE - 1)` and same for `T_BUSY` since you dont want to index with `BUF_SIZE`.

Comment: The problem was that I wrongly put "if"'s.